# is there another way to do this query? (contains a split string in linq-to-sql query)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an sql database with a table containing some products, each product can be produced on one or more machines. Now I want to search for all the products which are produced on a certain machine.

table is like this:

productreference(nvarchar) | machines(nvarchar)

P1               | 1,2,3

P2               | 2

P3               | 2

P4               | 2,3

I have tried to use the following query but I found out that linq-to-sql doesn't support the split string.

```
    public List<string> GetReferenceForMach(string machName)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> producttmp = from product in productInfo
                                         let machines = product.Machines.Split(',')
                                         from machine in machines
                                         where machine == machName
                                         select product.Reference;

        return producttmp.ToList(); 
    }
```

Is there another way to program this?

Comment: Is there any reason not to normalize the tables?

Comment: Out of the scope of your question, but I agree with Snowbear, your tables should be normalized here, OR try a document database like Mongo DB instead.

Answer (score 3):

When life gives you strings in a database, the normal response is to use string parsing:

```
string machName;

string midName = ',' + machName + ',';

from product in productInfo
where (',' + product.Machines + ',').Contains(midName)
select product.Reference
```

There is no indexing to help this query - so brace for a table scan.

Comment: From MSDN, here is the list of unsupported linq to sql String methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx

Comment: Thanks this helped me in the right direction.The contains(midname) didnt work, had to use IndexOf instead.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL is *good* but its not **magic**!  It still has to reduce your query down to executable SQL (which is why functions like `string.Split` are disallowed - they make it difficult to generate equivalent SQL).  In this case you are asking for something that simply can't be done by SQL server (searching based on the content of a comma separated field).

If you want this to perform like I think you expect it to then you need to change your database schema so that `Machines` has its own table and so can be indexed and queried effectively.

Alternatively you can fetch the whole table / resultset using Linq to SQL, and then use good old Linq to Objects to do the hard work:

```
IEnumerable<string> producttmp = from product in productInfo.AsEnumerable()
                                 let machines = product.Machines.Split(',')
                                 from machine in machines
                                 where machine == machName
                                 select product.Reference;
```

*(Not tested)*

Comment: ok I tried this, but it gives an unhandled exception at the return line: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return productInfo.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(p => p.Machines.Split(',').Contains(machName))
                  .Select(p => p.Reference)
                  .ToList()
```

The AsEnumerable() brings down the entire table and reduces the query to linq-to-objects. The downside of this method obviously  is that it could be very inefficient if you your table is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me,

It works now, I used the following code:

```
        IEnumerable<string> producttmp = from product in productInfo
                                         let midName = "," + machName + ","
                                         let checkMachines = "," + product.Machines + ","
                                         where (checkMachines.IndexOf(midName) > -1)
                                         select product.Reference;

        return producttmp.ToList();
```